# Maximum/minimum value of #define values

Tags: c, types

When using the #define command in C, what is the maximum or minimum amount the variable can be? For example, is

```
#define INT_MIN (pow(-2,31))
#define INT_MAX (pow(2,31))
```

an acceptable definition? I suppose a better way to ask is what is the datatype of the defined value?

Comment: In C, `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` have values specified in the standard header `<limits.h>`, and it is not a good idea to define your own unless you like confusing yourself and/or other programmers who need to understand your code.    Both `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` (or the values they yield) are allowed minimum magnitudes to `32767`.   So `INT_MIN` is guaranteed to be `-32767` or less and `INT_MAX` is guaranted to be `32767` or more.   The actual value of both is implementation defined (i.e. consistency is not guaranteed between compilers and libraries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` performs token substitution. If you don't know what tokens are, you can think of this as text substitution on complete words, much like your editor's "search and replace" function could do. Therefore,

```
#define FOO 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
```

is perfectly valid so far — that just means that the preprocessor will replace every instance of `FOO` with that long number. It would also be perfectly legal (as far as preprocessing goes) to do

```
#define FOO this is some text that does not make sense
```

because the preprocessor doesn't know anything about C, and just replaces `FOO` with whatever it is defined as.

But this is not the answer you're probably looking for.

After the preprocessor has replaced the macro, the compiler will have to *compile* whatever was left in its place. And compilers will almost certainly be unable to compile either example I posted here and error out.

Integer constants can be as large as the largest integer type defined by your compiler, which is equivalent to `uintmax_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`). For instance, if this type is 64 bits wide (very common case), the maximum valid integer constant is 18446744073709551615, i.e., 2 to the power of 64 minus 1.

This is independent of how this constant is written or constructed — whether it is done via a `#define`, written directly in the code, written in hexadecimal, it doesn't matter. The limit is the same, because it is given by the compiler, and the compiler runs after preprocessing is finished.

EDIT: as pointed out by @chux in comments, in recent versions of C (starting with C99), decimal constants will be signed by default unless they carry a suffix indicating otherwise (such as `U`/`u`, or a combined type/signedness suffix like `ULL`). In this case, the maximum valid unsuffixed constant would be whatever fits in an `intmax_t` value (typically half the max of `uintmax_t` rounded down); constants with unsigned suffixes can grow as large as an `uintmax_t` value can. (Note that C integer constants, signed or not, are never negative.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now and it makes sense.

Comment: "the maximum valid integer constant is 18446744073709551615" --> No.  The preprocessor does understand some C things.  Use "18446744073709551615u", add `u`.

Comment: You can try to run just the preprocessor (e.g., `gcc -E`) on a file using either of the two silly `#define` snippets I posted; you'll see that they work. As for the constant, you'll be right on the latest versions of C. (In C90, this would have been valid; the constant would have been unsigned by default if it didn't fit otherwise. A surprising backwards incompatibility.)

Comment: Note C90 only required up to 32-bit types.  `18446744073709551615` would still be a problem there on common C90 implementations.  `4294967295` was fine on C90 and C99.

Comment: Minor edit applied.  The issue is a decimal constant one and `L`, `LL` do  not affect sign-ness.

Comment: @chux Thanks! I added back the `ULL` case because I wanted to show that it's not _only_ `U`, but I made the example clear.

Comment: @Note that with PP math the `L`, `LL` are irrelevant. `#define A 1000000000 #define B 8000000000 #if A*8 == B` is true even without an LL on `1000000000` - it is still   `intmax_t` math.

Answer (score 0):

`#define INT_MIN (pow(-2,31))` is not acceptable, as it forms a maximum of the wrong *type*.

`pow()` returns a `double`.

Consider this: `INT_MIN % 2` leads to invalid code, as `%` cannot be done on a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is ill-advised for a number of reasons:

- These macro names are used in the standard library header *limits.h* where they are correctly defined for the toolchain's target platform.
- Macros are not part of the C language proper; rather they cause replacement text to be inserted into the code for evaluation by the compiler; as such your definition will cause the function`pow()` to be called everywhere these macros are used - evaluated at run-time (repeatedly) rather then being a compile-time constant.
- The maximum value of a 32 bit two's complement integer is not *2<sup>31</sup>* but *2<sup>31</sup> - 1*.
- The `pow()` function returns a `double` not an integer - your macro expressions therefore have type `double`.
- Your macros assume the integer size of the platform to be 32 bit, which need not be the case - the definitions are not portable.  This is possibly true also of those in , but there the entire library is platform specific, and you'd use a different library/toolchain with each platform.

If you *must* (and you really shouldn't) define your own macros for this purpose, you should:

- define them using distinct macro names,
- without assumptions regarding the target platform integer width,
- use a constant-expression,
- use an expression having `int` type.

For example:

```
#define PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MAX ((int)(~0u >> 1u)) 
#define PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MIN ((int)~(~0u >> 1u))
```

Using these the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MAX ((int)(~0u >> 1u)) 
#define PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MIN ((int)~(~0u >> 1u)) 
int main()
{
    printf( "Standard: %d\t%d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf( "Mine:     %d\t%d\n", PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MIN, PLATFORM_INDEPENDENT_INT_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Standard: -2147483648   2147483647                                                                                                                                                 
Mine:     -2147483648   2147483647
```